# .NET 2.0/3.5 application could not connect to a web service on Ubuntu 12.04 that forces connection to TLS 1.1

Tags: c#, https, mono, openssl, ubuntu-12.04

I have a client application written and compiled in C# 2.0 successfully referenced and call to my web service on local development server, using [Ubuntu 12.04](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_12.04_LTS_.28Precise_Pangolin.29) (Precise Pangolin) and [Mono](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_%28software%29) but never do update. Calling to a URL like

```
https://192.168.1.22/service.asmx
```

Then I upload this web service to the production server on [Amazon EC2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Elastic_Compute_Cloud) with the same configuration, but updated Ubuntu 12.04. In the client application only change the URL to `https://myserver.com/service.asmx`.

But my client application failed to connect. The debug message was shown as:

> Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.

I could open the web service description page on web browser so that mean the web service is working fine.

I took an hour trying to fix this, but no luck. Finally I found the deference between two servers.

In browser, the SSL connection of local server is using TLS 1.0 while the SSL connection of the EC2 server is using TLS 1.1. I googled and found .NET Framework 2.0 only supports TLS 1.0 and that.

I could not find how to disable TLS 1.1 in Apache 2.

I don't know if this is a bug in [OpenSSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSSL) on Ubuntu 12.04 or Mono or .NET. I am still trying to find a solution.

Comment: For temporary solution I set client to use SSL3 instead by using this code:

`System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;`